# how to use FluentValidation in angular?

Tags: angular, fluentvalidation

I want to check the validation rules using fluent validation.
like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluentvalidation-ts

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you having exactly?

Comment: I can't implement this concept because  there is form validation in angular

Comment: I want some implementation like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ts-flunt-validator?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Well, why are you then using forms, if you want to use some other validation library?

Comment: because this type of validation is FLUENT and its simple to use